# How to navigate inside UIContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uicontainerview

So I have a static upper part in my `UIViewcontroller` so I made `Container View` that has a static table view with two cell

Now I want when I click to one cell it shows the view inside that same container not in a new view (I have to keep the upper static content

I tried current context for modalPresentationStyle but it didn’t work

(I tried using the storyboard and programmatically from my `viewcontroller` that’s inside the container but neither worked)

So my question is the container the solution for my usecase ? And how can I navigate inside the container without the new `viewcontroller`  open in a new view

Here is a screenshot of the storyboard (the pink view is the static one that have to contain a 3 button as a view) 
I’m still in the first one but I have to open the 3rd view inside the same container that use to have the first view)
[image]

Comment: Attach screenshots what you have done so far.

Comment: I added the screenshot, to explain my issue, from the 1st view controller I could call directly the 3rd one but I want to be able to replace the second cc with the third one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support navigation inside your container, you have to embed your `tableView` inside a `UINavigationController` and then add the navigation controller as a container instead.

This way, you can navigate inside the contained view. If, on the other hand, you want to navigate on the entire view, I suggest using a delegate pattern to let the parent controller know it has to continue with the navigation.

Comment: I update my question with a screenshot, as for the navigation I already have navigation, my issue is I want to show the 3rd view inside the container in the place of second view (like fragments in Android)

Comment: In that case, you do the same thing you did so far, just one level deeper if I read your issue correctly.